# How do I set the correct $PATH for Python in zsh?

Tags: python, path, zsh

Today I made the switch from bash to zsh. Among other things, I created a ~/.zshrc file. There were a few hiccups, though. One of them is that while I can still run Python programs that will output to the shell, before they do I get the following error:

```
new-host-3% python program.py
zsh: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.: no such file or directory
```

Here's my current, very basic ~/.zshrc:

```
Set $PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# Export to vim
export EDITOR="vim"
bindkey -v

## vi style incremental search
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey '^S' history-incremental-search-forward
bindkey '^P' history-search-backward
bindkey '^N' history-search-forward

## Make moving inside a directory easier
setopt AUTO_CD
```

What am I missing here? I've installed Python, zsh, virtualenv, &c via homebrew on OS X 10.6.8. I'm running Python 2.7.6.

Everything worked with bash; no errors. That makes me think the problem is zsh and its configuration.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`? The bad interpreter error shows an invalid path, as if `/usr/bin/python` were a broken symlink (it should be just an executable file).

Comment: The python interpreter itself is not stored in the framework directory (which, incidentally, should be `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`); that directory only contains the standard library.

Comment: @chepner Here's that output:

new-host-3% ls -l /usr/bin/python
    lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66 17 Dec  2012 /usr/bin/python -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc

Comment: Yeah, that looks very wrong. The `bin` directory does contain various Python interpreters of specific versions, but `/usr/bin/python` should not be a link (either symbolic or hard) to any of them, yet alone to `pydoc`.

Comment: I don't know; the executable that should be there has been overwritten by some unknown process. There might be other problems as well; I'd suggest making a backup and reinstalling the system to be safe.

Comment: I set my $PATH in ~/.zshrc to:

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin

Still getting the above error.

Comment: as @chepner pointed out, the problem is not the path, or zsh, but the python installation.  Listen to him.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` say? If there is any issue with the path, it is a far second in severity to the corrupt `/usr/bin/python`, which is why I suggest re-installing. Something broke the default Python installation pretty hard.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using? It has shipped with Python 2.7 for some time now.

Comment: @chepner See the above question. OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot that you already had that in your question. Re-reading the question to see if I can identify the PATH issue, but the broken system Python still looks pretty bad.